# iPhone / Objective C nested C structures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, data-structures, nested

Can someone confirm that nested C structures are NOT allowed in objective C.

And by nested structs, I mean the following;

```
struct Tex2D
{
    GLfloat u;
    GLfloat v;
};

// quad uv cords
struct TexQuad
{
    Tex2D   uv[4];
};
```

I seem to have all kinds of problems compiling this. It's difficult to find any documentation on this as this is perfectly valid c code.

Cheers
Rich

Comment: Perhaps saying the code *seems* perfect valid, stating that you haven't done C in a long time, or rephrasing the question would prevent down votes. Overall, it's a good programming question, it just doesn't seem like it at first from the explanation. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have there is not valid C code. Remember, in C, when you declare a struct variable, you have to explicitly refer to it as a struct, like this:

```
struct StructType myStruct;
```

The most common way I've seen this solved is to bundle the struct declaration with a typedef, like this:

```
typedef struct _Tex2D
{
    GLfloat     u;
    GLfloat     v;
} Tex2D;

// quad uv cords
typedef struct _TexQuad
{
    Tex2D       uv[4];
} TexQuad;
```

That way, you can then create new struct variables without having to use the `struct` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, damn I haven't done C in about 10 years ... I've become so used to c++. Thanks. Both answers are correct however I can only tick on of them. I ticked this one as it was more verbose.

Answer (score 5):

Like in C you have to use the keyword struct when referencing structs. :-)

```
// quad uv cords
struct TexQuad
{
    struct Tex2D       uv[4];
};
```

Works!

Comment: Thanks, damn I haven't done C in about 10 years ... I've become so used to c++. Thanks. Both answers are correct however I can only tick on of them. I ticked the one below as it was more verbose.